# Has anyone modeled a slightly charged universe?

Tags: electromagnetism, cosmology, charge

In this [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/298688/will-a-uniformly-charged-universe-expand-isotropically) OP asks for a prediction for the expansion or contraction, therefore a scale parameter $a(t)$, when Universe is not neutral but uniformly charged.

A result for this would be

> In a homogeneous universe filled with charged dust the Faraday tensor must be zero everywhere by symmetry (in spite of the charge) making the Einstein-Maxwell equation reduce to the standard Einstein field equation. Electromagnetism plays no role in determining the spacetime geometry.

As DFJ states

> However, intuitively I still think it is strange that a uniformly charged universe is the same as one with no charge.

I also find it odd. I'd like to ask you if (**Question**:) you are in knowledge of any models for a Universe that's "slightly" charged. With this I mean that: we do expect the [Universe to be neutral](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/695740/is-the-universe-electrically-neutral-at-big-scales/695747?noredirect=1#comment1557172_695747) because we see gravity as the force describing its dynamics despite Coulomb's law being $\sim39$ orders of magnitude stronger, but at the same time if positive or negative charges exceeds by only a small amount, this effect might not be noticeable when studying the motion of objects.

This might be equivalent to ask for a model of Universe being perturbed by a small amount of charge. How would it be?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to find a translationally symmetric solution to the Maxwell equations for uniform charge. Having zero field violates the equations, after all.

Comment: I think a charged universe model will naturally give rise to a rotating universe model. Even if the universe had a slight non zero charge, there was a time close to Big Bang, when these charges were close to one another , and since it is statistically unlikely that they were symmetrically distributed, they must have gained a non zero torque in the process of acceleration of universe. We don't have evidence for rotating universe model, so it's unlikely that universe is charged